# Passing an Object from LineCallbackHandler to ItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch

I am writing a batch application which reads line-by-line from a file, process the content and write to database. Am using `FlatFileItemReader` for reading from file.

The first line in the file is special (header) which is skipped using linesToSkip and processed using a `LineCallbackHandler` (`HeaderHandler`). The `HeaderHandler` builds a cache using the header information.

Now I want to make use of this cache within my `ItemWriter`. Am not sure how to pass the cache object I build within `HeaderHandler` to my `ItemWriter`. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

you have at least 2 possibilities:

1. use the StepExecutionContext as temporary memory for your data, take a look at the spring batch doc:
   [passing data to future steps](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps) (just ignore the promotionListener
   part) your headerHandler writes the cache into the context and the
   writer pulls the cache from the context
2. use a spring bean with either a custom DataObjectClass or String, Map, etc. which will be [injected](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators) in the headerHandler and the (custom)itemWriter both use it accordingly